Fixture in cypress
I'm trying to connect the fixture like this, use beforeEach
cy.fixture('tabNetwork.json').then(data => {this.data = data})
but Cypress gives me an error(Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'data')
Because this error occurred during a before each hook we are skipping the remaining tests in the current suite: ) , I don't understand what's wrong
I always do it, but now something wrong. How to fix this?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You cannot use an arrow function if you want to set a property of this.
In a Cypress test you must use a standard function, like so
.then(function(data) {this.data = data})

See Sharing Context
Or at the test definition level is fine, since arrow functions inherit parent this scope
it('test that uses a fixture', function() {

  cy.fixture('tabNetwork.json').then(data => {this.data = data})

See Scope difference between normal functions and arrow functions

Alternatively use require to read fixtures at the top of the spec
const data = require('../fixtures/tabNetwork.json');  // adjust relative path




thank you, I use this .then(function(data) {this.data = data}), and when I want to use fixture in test I also see error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data') code of my test AdminNetworks.dialogElements.comment().click().type(this.data.number)
